# setQuery is not a function

Tags: reactjs, api

I was making a React Movie Website in which you can search for movies and see all details about them.

And there is a default search: **pushpa**.

But I am stuck in one place.

The default search value is not there in the search bar but the `query` state is working fine.

When I change the default value of the query state is working fine but the `setQuery` is giving an error.

**context.js code:**

```
import React, { useEffect, createContext, useState } from "react";

const API_URL = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=APIKEY`;

const AppContext = createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState([]);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState({ show: false, msg: "" });
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("pushpa");
  const getMovies = async (url) => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const data = await res.json();

      console.log(data);

      if (data.Response === "True") {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setMovie(data.Search);
      } else {
        setIsError({
          show: true,
          msg: data.error,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`An Error Occurred: ${error.message}`);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies(`${API_URL}&s=${query}`);
  }, []);
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{isLoading, isError, movie}}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return React.useContext(AppContext);
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider, useGlobalContext };
```

**Search.js code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppContext, useGlobalContext } from './context';

const Search = () => {
  const { query, setQuery, isError } = useGlobalContext(AppContext);
  return (
    <>
      <section id="search-section">
        <h2>Search Your Favourite Movie</h2>
        <form action="#" onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault()}}>
          <input type="text"
          placeholder="Search Here"
          value={query} onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)} />
        </form>
        <div className="card-error">
          <p>{isError.show && isError.msg}</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  )
}

export default Search;
```

When I run my website and write something in the search bar, it shows an error:

```
Search.jsx:13 Uncaught TypeError: setQuery is not a function
    at onChange (Search.jsx:13:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:9288:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `query` and `setQuery` in `AppContext.Provider`.

Your `AppContext.Provider` component will look like this:

```
<AppContext.Provider value={{isLoading, isError, movie, query, setQuery}}>
    {children}
</AppContext.Provider>
```